# PHPEXCEL mysql php insert empty rows

Tags: mysql, validation, rows, phpexcel

I am trying to use phpexcel to let users upload a spreadsheet and insert into mysql. I have it working except if the user has blank rows in the spreadsheet it puts several unnecessary rows in the database.  I have read and mysql doesnt support check constraints and most of that would need to be done at the application level which is what I am trying to do. How in PHP could have it check if a specific column is empty and skip that row. Any help would be appreciated or if there is a better solution I am up for all options. I was trying for a while to get it that is the `bldg` column was empty than just skip that row but wasnt having any luck..

```
<?php require '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$path = "../upload/uploads/$Filename";


$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
$worksheetTitle = $worksheet->getTitle();
$highestRow =  $worksheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = 'L'; // e.g 'F'
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
$nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($path);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

echo '<br>Data: <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0"><tr>';
for ($row = 16; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {

echo '<tr>';
for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
$cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
$val = $cell->getValue();
if($row === 1)
echo '<td style="background:#000; color:#fff;">' . $val . '</td>';
else
echo '<td>' . $val . '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

for ($row = 16; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {

$val=array();
    for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
    $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
    $val[] = $cell->getValue();

    }


  $sql="insert into excess1(date_excessed, bldg, floor, jack, equipment_owner,     contact_name, contact_phone, qty, type_of_excess, asset_tag, service_tag, comments)
values('".$val[0] . "','" . $val[1] . "','" . $val[2]. "','" . $val[3]. "','" . $val[4].     "','" . $val[5]. "','".$val[6] . "','".$val[7] . "','".$val[8] . "','".$val[9] .     "','".$val[10] . "','".$val[11] . "')";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

   print "$result";
  }
   }
    unlink("../upload/uploads/$Filename");
?>
</article>
```

Comment: So why not test $val[1] and only do an insert if it isn't empty... if (!empty($val[1])) { }

Comment: I tried  if (!empty($val[1])) {
  print "Skipping Row";
 }
 else {
$sql="insert into excess1(date_excessed, bldg, floor, jack, equipment_owner, contact_name, contact_phone, qty, type_of_excess, asset_tag, service_tag, comments)
values('".$val[0] . "','" . $val[1] . "','" . $val[2]. "','" . $val[3]. "','" . $val[4]. "','" . $val[5]. "','".$val[6] . "','".$val[7] . "','".$val[8] . "','".$val[9] . "','".$val[10] . "','".$val[11] . "')";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

print "$result";}

any ideas on what I am doing wrong it keeps adding them regardless

Comment: actually i just got it Thanks i was doing it backwards 

 if (!empty($val[1])) {
  $sql="insert into excess1(date_excessed, bldg, floor, jack, equipment_owner, contact_name, contact_phone, qty, type_of_excess, asset_tag, service_tag, comments)
values('".$val[0] . "','" . $val[1] . "','" . $val[2]. "','" . $val[3]. "','" . $val[4]. "','" . $val[5]. "','".$val[6] . "','".$val[7] . "','".$val[8] . "','".$val[9] . "','".$val[10] . "','".$val[11] . "')";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

print "$result";
 }
 else {


print "nono";}
} 

is what it should have been

Answer (score 0):

```
                    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filename);
                    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
                    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
                    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
                    $allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);

                    $i=0;
                    foreach ($allDataInSheet as $value) {

                        if ($value === null){
                        continue;                                   
                        } //this is skipping empty rows

                        $data[$i]        = $value['A'];
                        $data[$i]        = $value['B'];
                        $i++;
                    }
```